# Migrate app with Hibernate+DataSource from Tomcat 7 to Weblogic 12

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, weblogic, datasource, weblogic12c

I have a webapp running on Tomcat 7. It uses Hibernate 4 to connect to a DataSource defined in Tomcat server.xml and context.xml files.

Due to internal company reasons I have to migrate the webapp to Weblogic 12. I have deployed it successfully, except for the connection with the database. I created a DataSource on Weblogic console and tested it through the Console, it works fine (JNDI name is `jdbc/MyAppDB`).

To run my application in Tomcat I only had to tell the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file to look for the datasource, but aparently it is not enough for Weblogic. I'm really confused on how to configure the DataSource Connection. Basic Questions are:

- Do I have to add other files to my Webapp? I've seen some people talking about files such as `context.xml` and `weblogic.xml`, but have no idea where they should go.
- Do I have to add properties to my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file?
- Should I have used the `jdbc` prefix when defining the JNDI name for the DataSource? Only used because that's how I have used on Tomcat

Below is my current `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and former Tomcat Datasource config.

**OBS**: the application structure was created with Maven.

### Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>   

        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyAppDB</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>

        <mapping class="org.my.app.model.ServerInfo"/>
        <mapping class="org.my.app.model.Parameter"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### Tomcat DataSource

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyAppDB" global="jdbc/MyAppDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="#####" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/myappdb"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I was defining the datasource path in a wrong way. It should only be th JNDI name. therefore, in my case, the datasource should be refered in hibernate.cfg.xml as:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/MyAppDB</property>
```

**EDIT:** It is also worth noting that at this point Weblogic 12c simply can work well with Hibernate 4.3.5+.  I have succeded with 4.1.1, though. Using old, deprecated, HibernateUtil methods such as `buildSessionFactory()`.

Comment: Felipe, I am having some problems using JNDI and Hibernate together. Did you have to create a context.xml file?

Comment: @Erick, no, I didn't.